# QGIS assign multiple points data to closest polygon

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, select-by-location

I've got two layers:

- point layer
- polygon layer

I need to add the points attributes to the polygon by location (if the point is on top of polygon add the atribute as a new field. I thought of using "join attributes by location" option but it only adds the first point that finds on top of the polygon and, as you can see, some polygons have more than one point on top.

[image]

I thought of using distance matrix too, to find which is the nearest polygon of each point, but i found that some points are on top of no polygon and with this methos i would assing it's properties to the closest polygon..

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: do you want to create summary statistics (e.g. sum of point values in the polygon) or do you want to add more columns to the polygon depending on the number of points in it?

Comment: the second one.

Comment: You may want to consider the analysis implications of doing this. You have a many (points) to one (polys) relationship. To do what you're describing you'd need x attributes for the polys where x is the max number of points for any one poly *times* the number of attributes for each point. And that means you get the same attribute values stored in different attribute fields. There are a number of ways to address this, but what you want to do with the data and to some degree what those attributes are (values? apartment numbers?) will dictate the best solution.